# JQuery | Find all "," (comma) in an <ul> and erase them / replace with ' '

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
   <ul class="tabbox">
      <li></li>
      ,
      <li></li>
      ,
      <li></li>
    </ul>
```

JQuery (My Idea - does NOT work)

```
$(".tabbox").replace(',' , ''); // This was my idea, and it does not work ..
```

How can I remove the , from the < ul > ?

Comment: does all commas comes after `</li>`

Comment: NOTE: bounty was added to acknowledge Alnitak great answer which is answering the question perfectly in my opinion. If you have something even better feel free to share, but that's not the purpose of my bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to clean the list and leave only the list items is such code:

```
var list = $(".tabbox");
var items = $(".tabbox li");
list.html("");
items.each(function() {
    list.append($(this));
});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/TS8Sd/

This will not only remove comma but any other text or elements that do not belong there.

Comment: Would upvote if I had votes left. Would be nicer with `var items = $("li", list);` though.

Comment: Thanks @baz I'm not familiar (yet) with such syntax - what's the advantage?

Comment: it's possible to clean out those nodes without rebuilding the `<ul>` - see my answer

Comment: @Shadow It will be quicker, because it only searches in the elements contained in `list`. See [Context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context).

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that you're asking the wrong question.

If the intent is to remove the spurious text nodes (which happen to contain commas) from between the `<li>` nodes, you should do this:

```
$('.tabbox').contents().filter(function() {
    return (this.nodeType === 3);
}).remove();
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/gN7yM/

Note the use of `.contents()` to ensure that text nodes are included in the results.

If instead you want to purify the code to remove *anything* that isn't an `<li>` from the `<ul>`, use this:

```
$('.tabbox').contents().not(function() {
    return (this instanceof HTMLLIElement);
}).remove();
```

FWIW, since @ShadowWizard reports that this doesn't with with IE < 8.0 I tried:

```
$('.tabbox').contents().not('li').remove()
```

and it *didn't* work.  Reading the jQuery source it seems that pure string selectors completely ignore text nodes, but this *does* work:

```
$('.tabbox').contents().not(function() {
    return $(this).is('li');
}).remove();
```

**EDIT** I've changed a couple of the examples above to use `.not()` instead of `.filter()` so as to remove the double negative.

Comment: +1 for the correct way (one never stop learning! :)) however what about [such case](http://jsfiddle.net/gN7yM/2/)?

Comment: then change the filter test to `return !(this instanceof HTMLLIElement);`  - see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/gN7yM/3/

Comment: Nice, though IE support it only from 8 and above. (5% still use IE7 so thought it's worth mentioning :))

Comment: or `!($(this).is('li'))` for the broken browser... ;-)

Comment: Great stuff, would have given +3 if I could! :-D

Comment: @Alnitak sure thing! Ended up giving you +110 (6 additional upvotes are direct cause of post I made in Meta :)) and this answer deserve any point. Just keep up the excellent work! :)

Comment: Cheers - I saw the uptick when you posted the bounty, but I never saw the Meta post, BTW.

Comment: It's there somewhere, I asked if it's OK to use bounty as a way to recognize good answer and referenced this answer.. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var tabbox = $(".tabbox"),
    tabHtml = tabbox.html();

tabbox.html(tabHtml.replace(/,/g , ''));
```

This would replace all of them.

EDIT:

Although, why would you have a ',' after each li?

Comment: Unnecessary to use the `'.tabbox'` selector twice. You could save it in a variable.

Comment: Server side language sometimes creates "noise" so it can be easier to remove such noise client side instead of server side. I guess that's the case here..

Comment: I noticed that @Gaurav's answer was almost right, so I just used his. I'll ammend it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var tabHtml = $(".tabbox").html();
$(".tabbox").html(tabHtml.replace(/,/g , ''));  //@Tomgrohl already answered it
```

Comment: This does work BUT - it only erases ONE , - the last , is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

My example makes use of the [function parameter for `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

```
$('.tabbox').html(function (index, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(/,/g, '');    
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TyX6P/4/)

Comment: By using `text` you "ruin" the list, try adding text to the items and see what happens..

Comment: @Shadow Oh true, thanks. Fixed my answer. You could remove the downvote :).